# Java Spring Jackson json library returning unicode instead of text

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I am using this tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

to return JSON from my Java Spring web application. When I return a String over 1000 characters in object, the characters are converted into \u0000 just for that String value. The string is fine before it is returned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That means that your string contains null characters. Without more details (the CODE), we can't explain why.

Comment: At 999 characters it sends it fine, at 1000 characters it goes to encoded. Why would it chance all characters to null characters at 1000 characters?

Comment: You have a better chance of finding that out yourself, because you have the code and everything else at your disposal. We don't have anything, because you chose not to post a single line of code.

Comment: Actually the tutorial shows everything I am doing. If you need some specific based on that, I can post it.

Comment: I don't need anything. You do. You should post everything you think is necessary to help people help you, instead of hoping they will guess what your problem might be and fight to get information.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a solution but it's an issue with the `UTF8JsonGenerator` that Jackson provides. If your string is > 1000 characters in length, it calls `_writeLongString(_charBuffer, 0, len)`. The variable `_charBuffer` is just a 4000 character null buffer (each value in it is set to "\u0000") so you get a `len`-many character string of "\u0000".

EDIT: Upgrading past version 2.6.0-rc1 should be the fix (via https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/194)

Comment: Thanks for the non-snarky response. I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!