# Are my json stored in postgres corrupted?

Tags: java, postgresql, utf-8, jackson

I implemented a Java pipeline which stores some objects in postgres (9.5).

Objects are first serialized to a json string with jackson (2.5.4) and then sent with JDBC to the DBMS in a JSON column type.

When needed objects are read from database, deserialized and used by the application.

The problem is that when i try to query my data with psql I have some strange error, linked with UTF-8:

```
kronos=# select payload from messages where payload->>'errorMessage' = 'some error';
ERROR:  unsupported Unicode escape sequence
DETAIL:  \u0000 cannot be converted to text.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1:
...globalIdResolution":"GENERATED","authorFullName":...
```

I am not particularly worried, since my application can write and read all the data in the RDBMS. Is this a psql issue or maybe I am doing something wrong? Is there a way to be sure that my data should be accessible from any application, also if not java+jackson based?

I think this couldn't be jackson's fault, since I tried with a unit test but the string doens't seem to contain \0000 char:

```
package it.celi.dd.kronos.json;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonUTF8Test {

    @Test
    public void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        final String utf8 = "؏ـــطــہ";

        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("content", txt(1600) + utf8 + txt(500));
        final String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        final int jsonBoilerplate = "{\"content\":\"".length() + "\"}".length();
        assertEquals(1600 + utf8.length() + 500 + jsonBoilerplate, json.length());

        System.out.println(json.length());

        assertEquals("{\"content\":\"" + txt(1600) + utf8 + txt(500) + "\"}", json);
    }

    private String txt(final int chars) {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < chars; i ++) {
            builder.append('a');
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671634/handling-unicode-sequences-in-postgresql)

Comment: Yes, I've seen this and other workarounds like this, but I was looking first of all for an explanation of the issue and maybe for a cleaner solution: why psql can't convert the Unicode which can be inserted into postgres?

Comment: The first sentence of the answer said that the \u0000 is a unicode sequence that is not allowed inside a string. As json format have to be a valid string the \u0000 just brakes the string format.

Comment: so the question is: why jackson generate unvalid json strings? Should I care of configuring it to save valid json strings? Or it's just the fault of psql cllient which can't handle them correctly?

Comment: Right, seems it is a Jackson issue as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993750/java-spring-jackson-json-library-returning-unicode-instead-of-text) maybe fixed in 2.6.0.

Comment: it is possibile, since I'm using 2.5.x version of jackson! Il try updating to the lastest version to fix it: thanks!!!

Comment: I'm sorry but I realized this is not the real problem :( the bug was in 2.6.0-rc1, not in 2.5.x. I also tried to reproduce the bug writing a json of more than 1000 characters. If 2.5.x had the bug, I would have always a 4000 char string as result, which is not.

Comment: So, could you update your OP with a small example that produce the issue? Adding the test you have done with different versions of Jackson.